# Heroku - what happened? `sql` is not a heroku command

Tags: sql, heroku, command-line

Today I needed to check something in an old RoR project hosted on Heroku and when I wanted to check the database, I ran:

`heroku sql`

But instead of getting into a command line where I can display data in database, I got this statement:

```
 !    `sql` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `ssl`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

What happened? Heroku has changed something or?
(`heroku open` works well)

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you mean: `heroku pg:psql`?

Comment: Ohh, what's that? :) I have been using `heroku sql` for like a year and I never had a problem with that, since today. Anyway, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should install [this plugin](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console) first.